Command-line tool to change the "size" of an SVG file?
This question may seem like a misnomer, because SVG files contain vector graphics that can be scaled to any arbitrary size. You generally wouldn't say that an SVG has a resolution of 300x400 pixels, as you might a JPEG or PNG image.
However, SVGs do have a set size at which most browsers and similar software will display them by default. You can use CSS to change this, but depending on the software you're working with this may not be possible.
SVGs can be scaled to different sizes in Sketch and Figma by pressing ⌘K or K respectively. Notably, this properly scales the thickness of outlines, something e.g. Affinity Photo seems to have trouble with.
However, I have a very large number of SVGs that I need to scale down to exactly half of their size (so a 400x400 pixel image would become 200x200 pixels). If I use a graphical program like Sketch to scale each image manually, it will take hours.
If I had a command line tool I could use to scale these SVGs, I could write a shell script and be finished in a few minutes. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any UNIXy command line software that can operate on SVGs.
Is there any command line software that can scale an SVG file down to a percentage of its original size, so that I can automate the process with a shell script?
